# How to run Scala code in Intellij Idea 10

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have simple problem. I installed idea and scala plugin.
Create project and add wants to run simple `println("Hello world!")`.

I create "scala script". Add this line. And when i run it, i have error `expected class or object definition`.

How can i can run it and see the output?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have a `package` statement at the top, do you? (there shouldn't be)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Getting Started with IntelliJ IDEA Scala Plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/SCA/Getting+Started+with+IntelliJ+IDEA+Scala+Plugin):

> You can also turn your Scala object into a script. Just remove all declarations from the file, leave the executable statement only - println("Hello, World!"), and run the script as described above.

However I confirm that it results with the same error as you quoted. I think this is a bug (or inaccurate documentaion), file a [bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues), Jetbrains guys are developing this plugin very actively.

Answer (score 30):

I have just installed idea + scala plugin and had the same error on running my 1st "hello, world".

I solved it with Run -> Edit Configurations... -> select the script run configuration -> untick "Make" under "Before launch"

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the problem!