# Running IntelliJ scala project error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-15, scala-script

I am not using IntelliJ 15 for a long time, but never ever had such an issue. When I do: New Project -> Scala, then everything works fine, but when I do New Project -> SBT, then I can't even have main, because it gives me this:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testing
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)`

I did try deleting `Make` from `Edit Configurations`, I also tried adding `Scala script` in `Edit Configurations`, but still have this problem (it says scala script couldn't be found even though I linked it properly). Also, I read this topic:

[How to run a Scala script within IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087105/how-to-run-a-scala-script-within-intellij-idea)

but haven't found solution. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Took me some time, but fixed - the problem was pretty much obvious. It was enough to go: `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Modules` and add to `Source Folders` places where you create your scala file, or simply create scala script file in `main` -> `scala`.